# How to find words with REGEX using Elixir

Tags: regex, elixir

Given this string `"NEWNEWNEW1"` I need to remove all the `NEW` from the string so that after I'm done replacing it, it would look like this `"1"`. So If I got this string `"NEWNEW1"` I would also return this `"1"`. So how can I use regex to pull out any instance of NEW?

Comment: Doesn't `Regex.replace ~r/NEW/, "NEWNEWNEW1", ""` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to use Regex for this particular case. This should do :

```
iex> String.replace("NEWNEWNEW1", "NEW", "")
"1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.replace ~r/(NEW)*, "NEWNEWNEW1", ""
```